# When uploading package I get an error

Tags: community

Error    :

> Upload Failed An unexpected error occurred when uploading your
>   package. Please contact Salesforce Support and provide the following
>   error code: 1692038511-28113 (1548969588)

Comment: Can you provide more informations please ? Explain in details what you did if you want us to help you !

Comment: I received this same error. Is there a contact email or method to reach Salesforce Support?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact SalesForce to request more information on Unexpected Errors. If you raise a case and quote the error code `1692038511-28113 (1548969588)` they will be able to provide more information on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Often this kind of errors are caused by non-compiling classes, triggers or VF pages. I suggest, that you check for that first. The easiest way to detect those errors is to deploy the whole package using the force.com migration tool or the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [good article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) published by the Apex PM on these types of errors and where to get help - raise a case if you a registered partner, or you can tweet @support with the error so they can take a look...

As an aside, I had issues like this with missing FieldSets, or including permissions sets that reference master/detail where master is a Standard Object...in case that's helpful